# Delphi SQL Date reading issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, delphi, date

I am currently creating a Delphi Application with SQL connections integrated.
SQL stores its date values in the format YYYY-MM-DD, however, when I read these values within my Delphi application, they are read in the format MM-DD-YYYY.

I have currently written the code to read the values of the dates from my database, however I am having trouble processing values which do not have 2 month integers or 2 day integers. For example, the date 17th of February 2013 would be read as '2/17/2013'

My current code separates the date into day, month and year. It works well for full dates (MM/DD/YYYY) as it reads the corresponding values within the text using the 'Copy' command within Delphi. When it reads a date which is in the format M/D/YYYY it does not copy the correct values from the string.

Is there any way to edit the string before I run my separation code, so that it forces the string into the format of MM/DD/YYYY. My idea is to write code to check the format of the string and then add any zeros which are missing: i.e change 2/17/2013 into 02/17/2013

I know I'm probably doing something to make things harder for myself, but this is my code at this point in time, so any help to fix my problem by adding to my current code would be much appreciated.

Thanks, A.

Comment: What is the datatype of the fields in the database?

Comment: wanna show us the place where you read your db field value? it can help a lot, but as an idea, you can do Query.FieldMyDateTimeField.AsDateTime => TDateTime value which you can then format as you please i.e. DateToStr(MyDateTimeValue, MyTFormatSettings);

Comment: they are datetime values within mysql and string values within my dlephi application - using Fields[i].AsString to read the values from a DBGrid

Comment: I've changed my code to read the values as TDateTime values, however, they are in the same format of MM/D/YYYY. How would I use the TFormatSettings to configure the layout of these values? thanks, A

Comment: @user2057482 declare a variable as TFormatSettings and set the date and/or time format as you please, i.e. MyFormatSettings.Short|LongDateFormat, MyFormatSettings.Shot|LongTimeFormat, etc. don't forget about the MyFormatSettings.Date|TimeSeparator char

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo thanks for that. I'll have a read on Date FormatSettings and mess around with the code. Thanks for the help

Comment: Your problem is that you are converting to string. Store your dates as `TDateTime`. Then convert them to string only when you need to display as text.

Comment: Even when I store my dates as TDateTime within delphi, the Format of the dates does not follow DD/MM/YYYY when the days or months are not double digits. I'll look into ComputerSaysNo's response and post back, if it works. If anybody else has any ideas, i'd appreciate hearing them

Comment: @user2057482 That makes no sense. A `TDateTime` is simply a double precision value representing the number of days since the Delphi epoch. It doesn't have the form DD/MM/YYYY or anything like that. If you want to format it a particular way then feel free to do so. Any text you have is formatted the way you choose to format it.

Comment: use formatdatetime('dd/mm/yyyy', TYourDate) to convert a TDateTime to the formatsetting you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. I've managed to use the Date Formatting to convert my dates into the form I want them. They now store with the leading zeros when needed. Much appreciated.

Comment: Also you can use DecodeDate to decode DateTime types and EncodeDate to encode them also you might use VarToDateTime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, don't treat TDateTime values as strings, but as dates and times.

Don't get the value of a Date/Time field with the AsString method, use the AsDateTime method and assign it to a TDateTime variable.

If you want to know the date parts, use the provided functions to do so. For example the ones available in the [DateUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.DateUtils) unit. The [SysUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils) unit also contains some Date/Time related functions.

```
uses
  DateUtils, SysUtils;

var
  MyDate: TDateTime;
  MyDay, MyMonth, MyYear: Word;
begin
  MyDate := MyQuery.Fields[3].AsDateTime;  //not AsString
  MyDay := DayOf(MyDate);
  MyMonth := MonthOf(MyDate);
  MyYear := YearOf(MyDate);
  ShowMessage(Format('Day: %d, Month: %d, Year: %d', [MyDay, MyMonth, MyYear]);

  //or also
  MyDate := EndOfTheMonth(MyDate);
  DecodeDate(MyDate, MyYear, MyMonth, MyDay);
  ShowMessage(Format('Day: %d, Month: %d, Year: %d', [MyDay, MyMonth, MyYear]);
```

The same applies to storing values to the database, rather than use a fixed date format, use parameters, like this:

```
uses
  DateUtils, SysUtils;

var
  MyDate: TDateTime;
  MyDay, MyMonth, MyYear: Word;
begin
  MyDate := EncodeDate(2013, 2, 17);
  MyQuery.SQL.Text := 'insert into myTable (MyDate) values (:MyDate)';
  MyQuery.Params.ParamByName('MyDate').AsDateTime := MyDate;
  MyQuery.ExecSQL();
```

It works with all the database access layers available that I know of.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jachguate - I'll look into using parameters when storing values into my database, and have a play around with my code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Delphi, but if it's anything like .net, ColdFusion, php, or any other application technology, the principles are the same.

First, since you have a datetime datatype in your db, the only time format matters is when you display it.  Dates are numbers, not strings.

Next, query parameters are your friend for a variety of reasons.  If you can create a datetime variable in Delphi, and send it to MySql as a parameter, life will be very good.

Comment: At the moment, I need to use these values to link with dates within my application. So when a user selects the date '17/02/2013' from a calendar, the corresponding items with the date '02/17/2013' from my dbBgrid are selected. Hence my issue with handling the values.

Apologies if I am having trouble understanding your comment.

Comment: With the other technologies I mentioned, if a user selects '17/02/2013', the application code would convert that string to a Date or DateTime object.  I don't use Delphi but google led me to a page on a function called StrToDateTime.  Also, this page, http://delphi.about.com/od/database/l/aa050101a.htm, shows you how to use query parameters.

Comment: Thanks @Dan Bracuk - I managed to use the StrToDate function and set my own format using "ShortDateFormat := 'dd/mm/yyyy';" - this allows me to mess around with the format as needed. I'll have a read into the link you sent me. Thanks for the help. A.